# refreshing controls in knockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js, refresh, controls

I am new to KnockoutJS. I have a form with a dropdown. When user selects 'Current' option one div is made visible using visible binding and when 'Future' is selected another div is made visible. However, the controls retain their values while switching between views. Please guide. Here is the HTML

```
    <div class="row row-content">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h4>Select Planning</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="requestType" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Planning Type</label>

                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <select style="width:350px" class="input-md" data-bind="options:  $root.DayRequests, value: selectedRequestType,  optionsCaption: 'Select current / future'"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Current day request-->
<div class="container-fluid" data-bind="visible: showCurrent">
    <h4>Current Day Request</h4>
    <div class="row row-content">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:chkTownHall">Townhall(s)</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:chkSales">Sales Meeting</label>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:chkGroups">Groups</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:chkConference">Conference</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
<!--future Day Request-->
<div class="container-fluid" data-bind="visible: showfuture">
    <h4>Future Day Request</h4>
    <div class="row row-content">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:chkTownHallF">Townhall(s)</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:chkSalesF">Sales Meeting</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:chkGroupsF">Groups</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:chkConferenceF">Conference</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

AND here is script

```
    <script>
    var myViewModel = {
        DayRequests: ko.observableArray(['Current', 'Future']),
        selectedRequestType: ko.observable(),
        showCurrent: ko.observable(false),
        showfuture: ko.observable(false),
        chkTownHall: ko.observable(false),
        chkSales: ko.observable(false),
        chkGroups: ko.observable(false),
        chkConference: ko.observable(false),
        chkTownHallF: ko.observable(false),
        chkConferenceF: ko.observable(false),
        chkGroupsF: ko.observable(false),
        chkSalesF: ko.observable(false)
    };
    myViewModel.selectedRequestType.subscribe(function (requestTypeVal) {
        if (requestTypeVal == 'Current') {
            myViewModel.showCurrent(true);
            myViewModel.showfuture(false);

        }
        else if (requestTypeVal == 'Future') {
            myViewModel.showCurrent(false);
            myViewModel.showfuture(true);
        }
    });
    ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
</script>
```

Comment: Please show  more code snippet. your model what you've done

Comment: I have posted some sample code to demonstrate the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can have an instance of currentVM and FutureVM inside your main view model. Then each time that you switch between your options you create a new instance of PlanViewModel (sub model).

Example :https://jsfiddle.net/9aLvd3uw/253/

HTML :

```
<div class="row row-content">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h4>Select Planning</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="requestType" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Planning Type</label>

                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <select style="width:350px" class="input-md" data-bind="options:  DayRequests, value: SelectedRequestType,  optionsCaption: 'Select current / future'"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Current day request-->

<div class="container-fluid" data-bind="visible: ShowCurrent">
    <!-- ko with: CurrentVM -->
    <h4>Current Day Request</h4>
    <div class="row row-content">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:chkTownHall">Townhall(s)</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:chkSales">Sales Meeting</label>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:chkGroups">Groups</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:chkConference">Conference</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
<!--future Day Request-->
<div class="container-fluid" data-bind="visible: ShowFuture">
    <!-- ko with: FutureVM -->

    <h4>Future Day Request</h4>
    <div class="row row-content">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:chkTownHallF">Townhall(s)</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:chkSalesF">Sales Meeting</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:chkGroupsF">Groups</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:chkConferenceF">Conference</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

JS:

```
var MainViewModel = function (){
    var self = this;
    self.DayRequests = ko.observableArray(['Current', 'Future']) ;
    self.ShowCurrent = ko.observable(false);
    self.ShowFuture = ko.observable(false);
    self.FutureVM = ko.observable();
    self.CurrentVM = ko.observable();
    self.SelectedRequestType = ko.observable();
        self.SelectedRequestType.subscribe(function (requestTypeVal) {
        if (requestTypeVal == 'Current') {
            self.CurrentVM(new PlanViewModel ());
            self.ShowCurrent(true);
            self.ShowFuture(false);
        }
        else if (requestTypeVal == 'Future') {
            self.FutureVM(new PlanViewModel ());
                self.ShowFuture(true);
                self.ShowCurrent(false);
        }
    });

  }
 var PlanViewModel = function (){
     var self = this;
     self.chkTownHall = ko.observable(false);
     self.chkSales = ko.observable(false);
     self.chkGroups = ko.observable(false);
     self.chkConference = ko.observable(false);
     self.chkTownHallF = ko.observable(false);
     self.chkConferenceF = ko.observable(false);
     self.chkGroupsF = ko.observable(false);
     self.chkSalesF = ko.observable(false);
    };

   var vm = new MainViewModel();
   ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

**Edit:**
There are some advantages using a function over an object literal (How you have defined your model) to define a view model.

- You have an immediate access to `this` so you can directly bind a computed observable or a subscribe function to the value of `this` inside the model's scope and can be called from a different model and scopes. Beside, the creation of your model actually gets encapsulated in one call. That's why I used and many people prefer to use this pattern.

So you can create a global variable with a new instance of `MainViewModel`(take advantage of the value of `this`) and then you will be able to pass that variable to any plugins you want here we are passing `vm` to the `knockout` to apply binding.

```
var vm = new MainViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: Matt, the solution you gave works great in my sample application. But the real application is using some plugin/router, durandal/binder. Therefore, the vm is declared at the bottom of code instead of  ko.applyBindings(new MainViewModel());   For eg:                                    var vm = {
      SelectedRequestType: SelectedRequestType
};
return vm;                                             So I am totally confused what should go in vm and what should go in MainViewModel. Can you please guide.

Comment: @SilverFish take a look at Edit section. Hope that helps

Comment: Matt, I have a follow-up question in the same context. I have edited original post. If you can please help.

Comment: @SliverFish It is better not to change your question because it would be confusing for another person looking at your question and seeing an answer which does not seem relevant to the question.